# Regular expression to replace only the first semi colon with a double quote

Tags: sql, postgresql, atom-editor

There is a data dump that is semi colon separated.

How to load that data to the Postgres SQL database?

```
City;Latitude;Longitude
London;51.50;0.12
Paris;48.85;2.35
```

I thought of preparing an insert statements from this data using Atom text editor.
But there comes another challenge the first semi-colon needs to be substituted with a single quote and a comma to make a valid insert statement.

DDL for the table:

```
create table cities (
    name varchar(100),
    Latitude float,
    Longitude float
);
```

The insert statement should look like this:

```
insert into cities values('London',51.50,0.12);
insert into cities values('Paris',48.85,2.35);
```

But I was able to generate only this by using atom text editor:

```
insert into cities values('London,51.50,0.12);
insert into cities values('Paris,48.85,2.35);
```

The above is achieved by replacing semi colon with comma. Using `^` to add `insert into cities values('` in the beginning and `$` to add `);` in the add.

So the question is, what should be the regular expression to be used with atom text editor to replace the first occurrence of the semi colon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to pre-edit your input string, nor separate each entry to an individual insert; it can be done in one Insert statement. You have a string with known number of components and a separator so use the function regexp_split_to_array splitting by semi-colon (;). Then insert directly into the table referencing the elements and casting as needed. See [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=519c6ee6ad1090f8f172579c30e36fa6).

```
with loc( loc_str) as ( values('London;51.50;0.12'), ('Paris;48.85;2.35')) 
insert into cities(name, latitude, longitude) 
     select loc_part[1], loc_part[2]::float,loc_part[3]::float
       from ( select regexp_split_to_array(loc_str,';') loc_part from loc) l;
```

You could also use COPY to load a staging table from a source file then populate your table from it using the essentially the same as above. (also in demo)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

find: `^(.+);(.+);(.+)`
replace: `insert into cities values('$1',$2,$3);`

(I recommend this free resource as a good way to experiment with regexes: https://regex101.com/)